# Complex conjugation of fractional powers

Tags: complex-numbers

I would like to know when the complex conjugate can be moved outside of a real power, i.e. when is it true that

$$(\overline{z})^p = \overline{z^p}$$

where $p$ is real?

I wrote $z$ in exponential form $z = re^{i \theta}$, which yields:

$$(\overline{z})^p = (re^{-i\theta})^p = r^pe^{-ip\theta} = \overline{r^pe^{ip\theta}} =  \overline{z^p} $$

so it seems like the answer is "always."  However, I am suspicious because [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) this is true when $p$ is an integer; presumably if it were true for all reals it would have said so.

$\textbf{1}$. Is it true that $(\overline{z})^p = \overline{z^p}$ for all real $p$, or just integers?

$\textbf{2}$. If it's just integers, is the only difficulty of extending it to $\mathbb{R}$ the multi-valued nature of fractional powers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ isn't an integer, you have to worry about branch cuts.  For example, if we take principal branches of roots, then $$(-1)^{0.5}=i.$$

However, $$(\overline{-1})^{0.5}=(-1)^{0.5}=i\neq -i=\overline{i}$$

I don't have a proof, but my intuition is that it's "typically" never true if $p\notin \mathbb{Z}$, unless you carefully fiddle with the branch cuts.